# Is web-sockets a good option to achieve persistent connection?

Tags: c#, websocket, outlook-addin

I need to achieve a persistent connection between my outlook client add-in application and email server application (which talks to Microsoft exchange server and does some actions on emails) which is hosted as windows service.

Actions such as adding categories/properties and moving of emails from/to folder has to be performed on real-time basis at outlook client side first(on failure try at server end) as soon as email is read by email server application whenever new email comes in.

So, is using `web-sockets` between outlook add-in client and email server application a good approach here to achieve this? If not please suggest me with a better one.

Please help me here with your inputs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're in control of both server and client side, both of them being custom applications?  No need for the overhead of a websocket when a normal one would suffice.

Comment: as @JamesThorpe notes - there's no need for web-sockets *specifically* here; however, it would *work*, so if you're using it because you have a convenient web-socket library/server already and you want it to deal with things like framing and well-defined semantics (so you don't have to), then... fine I guess?

Comment: Yes it's good enough approach, especially if you have little experience in implementing network communications with raw sockets (since that might be quite non-trivial).

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs.@Marc Gravell , yes i am using `websocket-sharp` library here but not using any ping/pong frames to check the connectivity between client and server instead using custom `keep-alive` message.